# Is there a way to get Facebook public data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I want to know if there is a way to get users public Facebook data (eg. User’s page likes, name, surname, e-mail (if public)...) Without asking a user The permissions, only public data.

I’ve just check The graph API but all of informations requires users permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible via Facebook Graph API. The web-crawl method could achieve it, but that's against fair practices.

Answer (score 0):

- Public data of users without there explicit authorization: not possible at all.
- Public data of Pages: Only possible by applying for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) first.

Scraping/Crawling is not a valid way, because Facebook does not allow it.